# Java Constructor weird behaviour

Tags: java, constructor, chaining

I've run this code

```
public class Redimix extends Concrete{

    Redimix(){
        System.out.println("r ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Redimix();
    }

}

class Concrete extends Sand{
    Concrete() { System.out.print("c "); }
    private Concrete(String s) { }
}

abstract class Sand{
    Sand(){
        System.out.print("s ");
    }
}
```

and it printed out `s c r` but what I was expecting is that only `r` my question what is the logical explanation for this?

if a parent base class is an abstract class that has a constructor and then we create another class then extend it to the base class (In our Case `Concrete` extends Sand) and we then create another class then extend it to the concrete class name (In our case redimix) will all constructors from the hierarchy will be called?(from top to bottom)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

A constructor of the superclass is *always* called as the first action of a constructor.

If you do not explicitly invoke a constructor of the superclass, the *default* constructor (the "no args" one) is implicitly invoked.

Answer (score 3):

That is correct. The parent object's constructor is always called before the childs. This ensures that the object is in a valid state and that the object that has extended another class can always know what state the object is in.

Here is the code that you provided, after the compiler has inserted the implicit constructor calls in on your behave. Note that super(); is always called first.

```
public class Redimix extends Concrete{

    Redimix(){
        super();
        System.out.println("r ");
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Redimix();
    }

}

class Concrete extends Sand{
    Concrete() { super(); System.out.print("c "); }
    private Concrete(String s) { }
}

abstract class Sand{
    Sand(){
        super();  // invoking the constructor for java.lang.Object
        System.out.print("s ");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In each constructor, parent constructor is also called.

Answer (score 0):

In every constructor, first statement is always `super()` which is calling super class constructor except for `Object` class

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand [constructor chaining](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2012/12/constructor-chaining-in-java-calling-another-constructor.html) for this. When you make a call to any constructor all the **super class constructors are invoked first**. In you constructor definition, if you dont have one **compiler will add a no argument call to super class constructor** something like this : `super();`

This is because, **all the class in the hierarchy must be build before you actual class**, because your class is dependent on its super class.

This class to the super class constructor should always be the first statement in your constructor definition because they must be build before this concerned class. So **Object class constructor is always the first to be executed.**